# C++ weird behaviour with stack variables and functions

Tags: c++, variables, stack, rule-of-three

I've got a `String` class with a `char* buffer` and a `unsigned int length`.

The string class has two constructors:

```
String(const char* str);
String(const String& other);
```

and a destructor

```
 ~String()
```

which deletes the char array with `delete[] buffer;`.

Both constructors create a new buffer array `buffer = new char[size];` and fill it with the correct data from either the `const char* string` or the `const String& other`. The string buffer is null-terminated.

In my main function I've got the following code:

```
int main() {
    String a("Hello");
    a = a.Replace('l', 'p');
    printf("%s\n", a.char_ptr());
}
```

I would expect it to print `Heppo` to the console. The `replace` function takes two characters where all occurrences of the first one are replaced by the second one. It returns an entirely new `String`:

```
String String::Replace(const char& a, const char& b) {
    const char* buf = ...;
    // Do the replacement and store the result in buf

    String s(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return s;
}
```

From my understanding, the compiler will return a copy of the local variable `s`. Because of that, the `a` variable in `main()` should be a perfectly legitimate `String`. But the output to the console looks like `¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦`, which looks like uninitialized memory.

Even weirder, when i change my main method to:

```
int main() {
    String a("Hello");
    String b = a.Replace('l', 'p');
    printf("%s\n", b.char_ptr());
}
```

I see the expected output. After a lot of reading I could not figure out the solution, as this is problem is really hard to describe in a google/stackoverflow search.

Comment: You need an assignment operator

Comment: `a = a.Replace('1', 'p');` Did you define a copy-assignment operator?

Comment: Take a look at [the Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: That makes sense. What should the return value of the oprator be? I was thinking just a plain String: `String String::opreator=(const String& other)`

Comment: Copy assignment should return `String&`, not `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main problem is violation of the rule of big 3. since you have a none trivial destructur, you must also define a copy constructor and an assignment operator.
you may consider the copy-swap idiom in implementing the above functions.
Not definining either of the two in presence of a none-trivial destructor, leads to resource(memory in this sample) leak.